# How to save multi array to database using ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, pdo

I want to save an array passed from Ajax to PHP to different columns of the table.

Here are the arrays that Ajax sends to PHP:

I get this on the browser network header after clicking the save button.

Form Data:

```
tableArray[0][]:awdawd
tableArray[0][]:awdawd
tableArray[0][]:Male
tableArray[0][]:<button class='delete'>Delete</button>
tableArray[1][]:awdaw
tableArray[1][]:awdwa
tableArray[1][]:Female
tableArray[1][]:<button class='delete'>Delete</button>
```

My problem is after clicking the save button it only saves the name part of the array to the table:

[image]

script:

```
$("#saveTable").click(function(){
 $.ajax(
    {
    url: "saveTable.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { tableArray: dataSet},
    success: function (result) {

    }
});  
});
```

saveTable.php

```
<?php
    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $db = "test";

    $dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db, $user, $pass);
    $dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $tableArray = $_REQUEST['tableArray'];

    foreach( $tableArray As $v){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO viewTables (name, age, gender, action) VALUES ('$v[0]','$[1]','$[2]','$[3]')";
    $query = $dbc->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sadiq pointed out the problem, which is simply a typo. Let me suggest however that you actually use prepared statements in a better manner, by only preparing the statement once and using parameters to prevent against SQL injection.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO viewTables (name, age, gender, action) VALUES (:name, :age, :gender, :action)";
try {
    $sth = $dbc->prepare($sql);
    foreach( $tableArray As $v){
        // bind parameter values
        $sth->bindValue(':name', $v[0], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $sth->bindValue(':age', $v[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindValue(':gender', $v[2], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindValue(':action', $v[3], PDO::PARAM_STR);      
        $sth->execute();
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    // something went wrong
    // log an error or whatever
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO viewTables (name, age, gender, action) VALUES ('$v[0]','$[1]','$[2]','$[3]')";
```

should be

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO viewTables (name, age, gender, action) VALUES ('$v[0]','$v[1]','$v[2]','$v[3]')";  // Added array name for the last three values
```